# System.Net.Http.HttpClient adds @ at the end of JSON keys. Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, httpclient

I have a pretty simple problem I am not able to solve.

I have an Action method defined like this:

```
    [HttpPut]
    public ActionResult Register(ClientRegistrationInformation clientInformation)
    { ... }
```

ClientRegistrationInformation is defined in F# like this:

```
type ClientRegistrationInformation () =
    member val ClientKey = Guid.Empty with get, set
    member val ValidationToken = String.Empty with get, set
```

I want to call this action method using System.Net.Http.HttpClient. When I try this:

```
httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync (RegisterUrl, clientInformation)
```

the JSON content is sent like this, which does not work:

```
"{\"ClientKey@\":\"8cb33ed5-ef49-4c40-afbe-78f0c198448e\",\"ValidationToken@\":\"token\"}"
```

When I try the same using jQuery.ajax, the content is sent like this, which DOES work:

```
"{\"ClientKey\":\"8cb33ed5-ef49-4c40-afbe-78f0c198448e\",\"ValidationToken\":\"token\"}"
```

Why does HttpClient add the unnecessary @ symbols at the end of the names?
How do I get rid of them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I found the problem. I was stupid.

Turns out that the automatic properties of F# are implemented in a way that the serializer picks up the backing field which is called the same as the property but with an additional @ at the end.

By changing the declaration of ClientRegistrationInformation, the problem disappeared:

```
type ClientRegistrationInformation () =
    let mutable clientKey = Guid.Empty
    let mutable validationToken = String.Empty
    member this.ClientKey
        with get () = clientKey
        and  set v  = clientKey <- v
    member this.ValidationToken
        with get () = validationToken
        and  set v  = validationToken <- v
```

Stupid mistake. :)

Comment: That's interesting, you might wanna consider reporting that as a bug to the F# team.

Comment: Actually, this is known behavior. MSDN even warns not to use them in frameworks (see Caution box): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483467.aspx